# How is nodejs able to handle more concurrent requests?

Tags: php, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency

I have been reading the following argument between `apache` and `nodejs`, which I do not understand.

`Apache` is thread and process based `i.e` each request is handled by a separate thread or process (depending upon configuration), which means if the process is waiting for the I/O, whole thread is blocked.

- What did I loose here? I will also wait when running nodejs, even if it means waiting asynchronously. Isn't it?

Every `nodejs` instance runs in a single thread and due to its asynchronous nature, it can handle far more number of concurrent requests as compared to `apache`

- Could anyone explain me how?

I have been trying to understand how nodejs scores and its main strong point, but I just do not get the essence of it.

Answer (score 2):

Apache is totally thread based as you described.WHile nodejs is event based.It uses event loop.
Now lets take a example.
Suppose you have thousands  of requests.In apache it will spawn thread for each and every request(Which is obviously have a bottleneck,You cant scale too much vertically to support this.)
While in node js 1 instance will have single thread.It doesnt blocks for an i/o.In mean time while i/o is there it can accept and start processing(cpu related) on the new request.
Concurrency is way higher in nodejs.As it allows many requests to be handled at the same time.However i donot have any benchmarking on whether request processing is bit higher in nodejs or not.But yes in terms of concurrency nodejs will defeat any of its competitors.

Comment: How does it handle concurrent requests with a single thread and without any lag. This is what I want to understand.

Comment: It uses event loop.Suppose you have a request , in thet request you are having i/o calls.While it has made i/o call...your cpu is free to process any other request.
And basically to understand this you have to understand event driven programming.
In nodejs general implementation is to have 
a central mechanism that listens for events and calls a callback function once 
an event has been detected (i.e. state has changed)

Answer (score 2):

For better understanding let's start from this picture:

[image]

And there are following steps:

1. Client sends HTTP requests to `NodeJS` server.
2. Requests come to `Event Loop` (single thread), which is woken up by operation system. It passes every request/response as Javascript closure to relevant worker functions with callbacks.
3. After that you do some operations (long-running jobs etc.) inside non-blocking workers.
4. As soon as it's done, response is sent back to main thread via callback.
5. In the end `Event Loop` returns result to client.

This way NodeJS main thread doesn't perform any operations by itself and only delegates management process to non-blocking workers where you can do your magic stuff concurrently.

**Note:** NodeJS can only receive or respond to a single request at a time. However, during the same time it can process multiple requests.

---

For example you have 100000 requests at a time. It really makes sense `blocking` or `non-blocking` operations you do in your requests handlers.

**Blocking** operations will block javascript processing since it's synchronous action takes place. This behavior can lead to server's halt.

**Non-blocking** operations will happen immediately, so everything will depend on [vertical scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Horizontal_and_vertical_scaling). It means it will receive/respond as fast as it's possible for current hardware configuration.

To increase your server performance:

- **Horizontally**, you might want to play with NodeJS [clusters](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html), load-balancer configurations etc.
- **Vertically**, you might want to play with [V8](https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html#v8_setflagsfromstring_string) engine. Look [here](https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-flags/blob/master/flags-0.11.md) to find more V8 flags. Or you can upgrade your hardware of course.

For example, [max_old_space_size](https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-flags/blob/master/flags-0.11.md#max_executable_size-0-integer):

```
–max-old-space-size=8192
```

> Increases the limit for each V8 node process to use max 8Gb of heap
>   memory instead of the 1,4Gb default on 64-bit machines(512Mb on a
>   32-bit machine).

Comment: What happens if there are `100000` concurrent requests? How is the single thread able to handle each of them? This is not possible without a considerable lag.

Comment: THere will be lag if your request needs alot of cpu processing tasks.BUt if it doesnot then it doesnot have that lag.
IN general scenario
request --> make database request
request --> make database request
request --> make database request
database request complete --> send response
database request complete --> send response
database request complete --> send response

Comment: @NitishAgarwal Does nodejs perform some magic? It is common sense, that the `1000 th` request will be handled after all other requests are handled and hence the lag. And how do you define `Intensive CPU Processing Task`. Is there a threshold value given by `nodejs` team?

Comment: @OlegMeleshko Will `apache` with `php` fair better in this situation? Also, for number of concurrent requests to be as low as `100` and let us assume handling each request takes `x seconds`, so the `100th` request will get processed after `100x` seconds. It seems very unfair.

Comment: @SuhailGupta depends on what you need. In case you serve static files - yes, apache or nginx is preferable, every file is loaded in dedicated thread/process which looks like a good way to go.